# how to list custom post type 'movies' with a genre of 'horror'

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

I have been trying to list my custom type 'movies' with the custom taxonomy genre with a value of drama. 
I have tried several solutions but as yet I have failed.

```
<?php

$args = array(
'post_type'     => 'movies',
'tax_query'     => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy'  => 'genre',
    'field'     => 'term_id',
    'terms'     => 'drama'
    )
)
);

$drama = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $drama->have_posts() ) : while ( $drama->have_posts() ) : $drama->the_post(); ?>


<h4><?php echo the_title(); ?></h4>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : echo '<p>NO CONTENT FOUND</p>'; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope someone can shed some light on this matter.

Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `field` parameter is wrong, in your case you need to set it to `slug` as drama is not a `term_id`

```
$args = array(
   'post_type'     => 'movies',
   'tax_query'     => array(
       array(
         'taxonomy'  => 'genre',
         'field'     => 'slug',
         'terms'     => 'drama'
      )
   )
```

);

Hope it works !

Comment: add 'posts_per_page' parameter to increase the results number.

Comment: no it is paginating the list correctly but not displaying it correctly lol :/

Comment: Post a new question with the pagination code and how you display it in the page ;-)